# Creating different Software Designs from one vary narrow requirement specification

Tags: software-design, system-design

I am helping a friend with his course work. Basically the project requirement is to create a software system to computerise a music shop that sells musical instruments. The essence is nothing more than a CRUD system with some reports and sales capturing component. He is however required to document three different design specification from which he will select the one to be developed. He has the design he wishes to proceed with but we are struggling to create to two alternative designs.

My difficulty is that, the requirement scope so narrow that, it's a challenge varying it enough so as not create a mere duplicate.

I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: When you say design - do you mean whether to use a regualr mvc framework vs  going for a REST web app?

Comment: No I don't think that is what is meant. The exact wording is "formulation of three possible initial, outline software project specifications"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your friend's professor has been in the classroom for too long. Essentially creating too much pointless work for students with questionable benefits. But nonetheless, if I understand your friend's challenge - creating three architectural approaches - I would recommend picking three starting points and building from there. For example:

> 1) Design a system with emphasis on the Music records, streaming, etc
>
> 2) Design a system with emphasis on User/Customer input, interaction
>   and rich User Interface.
>
> 3) Design a system with emphasis on the
>   purchasing experience and a Product centric data model.

In each case, you can intentionally under-build, under-design the other two components of your music shop just to create some distinction - when in fact we know the ideal solution should consist of all 3 architectural and design components.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that it basically what I was thinking. Thanks for your feed back.